# Madelineproto internal peer database error when try getFullUser

Tags: php

Help me please.

Through the Madelineproto library, I'm trying to get information about the telegram user, but I get an error:

> This peer is not present in the internal peer database

I tried like this and always got this error:

```
$MadelineProto->users->getFullUser(['id' => 'xxxxxx']);
$MadelineProto->users->getFullUser(['id' => 'user#xxxxxx']);
```

The documentation has the answer:

> this error means you have tried sending a message to a peer that does
> not exist or is not present in MadelineProto’s internal peer database:
> in fact, @dd is not a valid telegram username.

But I don't understand what that means, because I use my id, which is definitely working. What is an internal peer database and how to work with it to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `getFullInfo` method, instead.

Also, MTProto clients can't always resolve a user starting from their ID: they must've met the user before in some other context (a private chat, a group) in order to cache their information.
A username can also trigger caching of this information: try passing your username instead of your ID.

MadelineProto also has an optional `cacheAllPeersOnStartup` [setting](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/PHP/danog/MadelineProto/Settings/Peer.html) that can be enabled to pre-cache all users and groups in the dialog list on startup automatically.